# Unable to find mypy.ini configuration file on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I have installed the mypy module and want to update the module path in the config file. I tried to find the file mypy.ini but no success.

I am using Mac OS and python 3.7

I have gone through the documentation but it's not easy to understand for a new person like me 
[mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html)

Comment: Hmm, second sentence in the docs you have linked: _By default it uses the file `mypy.ini`  [...] in the current directory_ - why not start by creating one?

Comment: @hoefling I did the same as you mentioned and it worked... but still the mystery remains the same.. where to find the default mypy.ini file.. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to create a mypy.ini file if it does not already exist: mypy will not automatically create one for you. There is also no such thing as a "default mypy.ini file".